# Add treeview node by path

Tags: c#, treeview

I need add `TreeView Node` by path, example:

[image: TreeView]

And I'm trying to add from code:

```
public void AddParent(string path, string node)
{
    TreeNode parentNode = treeView1.Nodes[path];
    if (parentNode != null)
    {
        parentNode.Nodes.Add(node);
    }
}
```

Ex path: Node0\Node1\Node2
Ex node: Test

But parentNode returns always `null`.

Someone can help me?

Comment: I don't think treeView1.Nodes[path] works how you assume. It is the name/key/whatever of one child node on Nodes. E.g. your treeview.Nodes property in your screenshot has two child nodes named "Node0" and "Node3". But the treeview.Nodes["Node0"] has one child node called "Node1". To get to "Node2" you'd do something like this "var node2 = treeView1.Nodes["Node0"].Nodes["Node1"].Nodes["Node2"];"

Answer (score 0):

I solved my problem

First Check Nodes:

```
public void AddParent(string path, string node)
{
    foreach (TreeNode tnode in treeView1.Nodes)
    {
        if (tnode.FullPath == path)
        {
            tnode.Nodes.Add(node);
            break;
        }

        checkChildren(tnode, path, node);
    }

    treeView1.ExpandAll();
}
```

After, check children's:

```
public void checkChildren(TreeNode original, string path, string node)
{
    foreach (TreeNode tnode in original.Nodes)
    {
        if (tnode.FullPath == path)
        {
            tnode.Nodes.Add(node);
            break;
        }

        checkChildren(tnode, path, node);
    }
}
```

Thank's!